# Unable to write onto SDCard an XML file created through Simple XML Serialization

Tags: android, android-sdcard, simple-framework

I'm trying to serialize some sample data through the Simple framework. 
I have imported the Simple-XML jar (have not imported other jars like stax, xpp3 etc. which were the lib directory of the simple-xml archive I downloaded) file onto my android studio.

Here is the code which tries to create "example.xml" file (these lines are inside `oncreate` method):

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        Example example = new Example("Example message", 123);
        File result = new File("/sdcard/example.xml");

        try {
            serializer.write(example, result);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I have added the permission, required to write to the external SDCard, in the androidmanifest file.

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
1194-1194/com.test.app E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-28 10:13:35.395    1194-1194/com.test.app I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance, referenced from method org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamProvider.<init>
12-28 10:13:35.446    1194-1194/com.test.app W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 8650: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;.newInstance ()Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;
12-28 10:13:35.446    1194-1194/com.test.app D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
12-28 10:13:35.455    1194-1194/com.test.app W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader;)
12-28 10:13:35.465    1194-1194/com.test.app W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader;)
12-28 10:13:35.465    1194-1194/com.test.app I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.createXMLEventReader, referenced from method org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamProvider.provide
12-28 10:13:35.465    1194-1194/com.test.app W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8648: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;.createXMLEventReader (Ljava/io/InputStream;)Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader;
12-28 10:13:35.465    1194-1194/com.test.app D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-28 10:13:35.545    1194-1194/com.test.app I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.createXMLEventReader, referenced from method org.simpleframework.xml.stream.StreamProvider.provide
12-28 10:13:35.555    1194-1194/com.test.app W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8649: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;.createXMLEventReader (Ljava/io/Reader;)Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader;
12-28 10:13:35.555    1194-1194/com.test.app D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-28 10:13:35.785    1194-1197/com.test.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 240K, 12% free 2638K/2996K, paused 19ms+18ms, total 105ms
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The errors you get could originate from a library version conflict. I.e. another version of a library was used for compiling than at runtime. Another possibility if you use proguard: some extra configuration is necessary to keep the called methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think the file you are accessing hasn't been created. Use this code.

```
File result = new File("/sdcard/example.xml");
try {
     if(!result.exists()) {
         result.createNewFile();
     }
     serializer.write(example, result);
     } 
catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```